# How to close route popup before navigating to next location? (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm displaying a range of items you can click on to take you to the next route. You can also click on a popup on this page. If you click on the popup, and then click on one of the items I would like to destroy the popup before displaying the next route.

```
onSelect(id) {
    if (this.router.url.includes('popup')) {

      let p = Promise.resolve(() => this.closePopup())
      p.then(() => this.router.navigate(['/', id]))

    } else {

      this.router.navigate(['/', id])

    }
  }

closePopup() {
    this.router.navigate([{outlets: {popup: null}}])
  }
```

I don't really understand promises so I'm not sure I've written it in the correct structure, but this code isn't working as it will always navigate to the next route with the popup still inside the URL. I've tried to do it in the same structure outside the promise but it will always navigate to the :id with the (popup) still in the URL.

I have also tried: `this.router.navigate(['/', id, {outlets: {popup: null}}])`.

Is there a function within the router which allows an absolute rewrite of the URL? Or is there a way to ensure that it will remove the popup from the url before navigating to the :id.

Hope problem is clear - help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is a [bug report](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15338) filed on GitHub about this behavior.

According to it, `this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { popup: null } });` should work though.

But it's also possible to explicitly set the URL via `this.router.navigateByUrl('/')`, which should unset any named outlets.

Follow the GitHub issue, since it was just recently added to the backlog and might be fixed soon in an upcoming version of Angular.

Alternatively, you can find another possible workaround in [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15718):

```js
this.router.navigate([this.route.parent.snapshot.params, {outlets: {popup: null}}]);
```